# Remove lines containing different words

Tags: python, string, split

I am using this code to remove all the lines from a string containing the word "root":

```
output = str([line for line in output.split('\n') if 'root' not in line])
```

The string is something like this:

```
machine_name_root 35942400MB 27675648MB 23%                    
machine_name_2 665600MB   512512MB   23%
```

I would like to remove all those lines containing the word "displayed" too (If some line contains display or root, remove those lines), but doing this it does not work for root neither:

```
output = str([line for line in output.split('\n') if 'root' or 'displayed' not in line])
```

I also tried with this:

```
output = str([line for line in output.split('\n') if 'root' not in line or 'displayed' not in line])
```

But it is the same, it does not work for root or displayed.

Comment: ```output = str([line for line in output.split('\n') if 'root' not in line and 'displayed' not in line])```???

Comment: As @ggorlen says, you need to use `and` instead of `or`, because you want lines where none of both are in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `and` instead of `or`.

```
stringEx = """hello there buddy
how are you doing?
Welcome to your therapy session"""
newString = [lines for lines in stringEx.split('\n') if 'hello' not in lines and 'how' not in lines]
print(newString)
```

output

```
['Welcome to your therapy session']
```